# finding a function in c# based on a attribute value

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I want to access function of a class, through some adapter, based on a attribute value. all functions have the same prototype 
the way I thought to do it is to declare a Dictionary like that:

```
Dictionary<key_values, Delegate_of_Functions>
```

where `key_values` a class that contains the values that identify a function, and `Delegate_of_Functions` is a delegate of the functions type.

now, I tried to do the following:

```
Functions = new Dictionary<string, function>();

var a = from Fun in typeof(TheFunctionsContainer).GetMethods()
        where Fun.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(The_Attribute), true).Length != 0
        select Fun;

foreach (var c in a)
{
  Functions.Add(
    c.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<The_Attribute>().First().key,
    new function(c)); // this line dose not compile
}
```

my questions are:

- how to get the line that not compiles to compile?
- is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do all the functions have the same signature?

Comment: `Functions = new Dictionary<string, function>();` how does this line compile? What is `function`?

Comment: @AlexanderR yes, all functions are the same part to the name and body.

Comment: @ZaidMasud `function` is a delegate a declared in my code. it declared so it could refer to the functions i'm interested in.

Comment: Have a look at [`Delegate.CreateDelegate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate).

Comment: You may wish to rename `function` to something more appropriate. I like suffixing delegates with 'Delegate', so `MyFuncDelegate`; be descriptive! Likewise, `c` and `a` aren't terribly useful names either. Besides that svick's comment seems like the best place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `function` is a delegate

```
delegate void function();
```

you can use the [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx) method for creating a delegate

```
var Functions = new Dictionary<string, function>();

var a = typeof(TheFunctionsContainer).GetMethods().Where(f => f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(The_Attribute), true).Any());

foreach (var c in a)
{
    Functions.Add(
      c.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<The_Attribute>().First().key,
      (function)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(function), c)); 
}
```

If you  want to execute non-static methods on an instance, you have to provide the instance you want the methods call on to [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx):

```
(function)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(function), yourInstance, c)
```

or just see svicks comment :-)

Comment: You can use the first approach on instance methods too, you just have to add `this` as the first parameter of the delegate. So, for example if you have `MethodInfo` representing `string.Insert()`, you can turn it into `Func<int, string, string>` using your second approach, or `Func<string, int, string, string>` using your first approach.

Answer (score -1):

A straightforward way to do this is to invoke the [`Invoke` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx) on the methods you have found. You can do that in anonymous delegates added to your dictionary.

You say all of your functions have the same *prototype* (that's usually called a *signature* in C#), but as you don't indicate what signature that is, I'll simply assume a void method that takes a string and an integer (represented by an `Action<string, int>` in my sample code below). I trust you can change the code so it suits you :-)

Each element in `a`, that is, each `c` in your `foreach` loop, is of type [`MethodInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx):

```
var Function = new Dictionary<string, Action<string, int>>();

// your code for discovering the suitable functions and filling a

foreach (var c in a) {
    Functions.Add(c.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<The_Attribute>().First().key,
      (s, i) => {
          c.Invoke(null, new object[] { s, i });
      });
}
```

Before adding anything to that dictionary, you may want to check whether the `MethodInfo` instance indicates that the method *really* has the desired signature, though. Otherwise, someone might intentionally or unintentionally mark a method with a different signature with that attribute and the call to `Invoke` will fail.

Comment: This will use reflection on each call, which can be very slow. I think reflection should be used only to create the delegate, and not every time you invoke it.